# Ultra-efficient sound editing tips for battle scenes?

Tags: pro-tools, workflow, soundminer, efficiency

I am working on a feature using Pro Tools/Soundminer that has a lot of battle scenes- swords, punches, bow/arrow, grunts, etc. It's a lot of grinding covering every single hit in multiple chaotic battle scenes.

Are there any video tutorials/articles/blog posts that talk about how to cover a feature like this as efficiently as possible? Alternately, do any of you have any tips on handling an entire feature of this nature?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are some plugins that allow you to use a combination of altered pitch, volume and cut to more efficiently lay effects with variance so you don't fall into the trap of repeating the same effect over and over again.

Check out https://www.krotosaudio.com/products/reformer-pro/ and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a random midi notes generator to trig a sampler full of that kind of sounds.
Here is a tuto I made for my reel:
https://www.vincentfliniaux.com/single-post/2017/02/13/Generative-Music-Sound-Design-using-BIDULE
You can use Reaktor instead of Bidule.
Cheers.